# How can I fetch html tags in a HTML document

Tags: java, html-parsing

Hey I want to get tags from a html document.
That is everything that is contained within the angle brackets with the angle brackets inclusive.  How can I do this in Java ?
Thanks

Comment: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Answer (score 3):

```
<!-- Read carefully -->
<b><![CDATA[<Everything in angle brackets ("<>") is a tag?>]]></b>
```

... and use an html parser.

---

If you want to do it manually, iterate over the input chars and decide for each and every `<` and `>` whether it belongs to a tag element or not. There are some rules (processing instructions, comments, CDATA content, angle brackets in attribute values(!)) to follow.

Most parsers use some `switch/case` pattern for evaluating each token (char in your case).

Answer (score 2):

I used [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) recently. Nice API, easy to use and no problems so far. Don 't even try to parse html yourself. See Andreas_D answer.